# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'startswith' when using Python httplib

Tags: python

I'm trying fetch account information by python, which's OAuth 1.0. And I have the code below:

```
token_url = "oauth/token?" + urlencode(ksort(params)) + "&sig=%s",sig
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection(url, 443)
conn.request("GET", token_url)
```

Here it reports:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\windows\Desktop\https.py", line 35, in <module>
    conn.request("GET", token_url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 973, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1001, in _send_request
    self.putrequest(method, url, **skips)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 900, in putrequest
    if url.startswith('http'):
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

The connection is OK, but I can't go through the following https request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing a tuple instead of a string:

```
>>> sig = 'sig'
>>> 'oauth/token?blahblah&' + 'sig=%s', sig
('oauth/token?blahblah&sig=%s', 'sig')
>>> 'oauth/token?blahblah&' + 'sig=%s' % sig
'oauth/token?blahblah&sig=sig'
```

Replace the following line:

```
token_url = "oauth/token?" + urlencode(ksort(params)) + "&sig=%s",sig
                                                                 ^
```

with

```
token_url = "oauth/token?" + urlencode(ksort(params)) + "&sig=%s"%sig
```